# Custom Component in android

Tags: android

I have created custom component with a Button Bar on the Bottom of
the screen and a Title and status bar on the top of the screen. I want
to include this custom component in every one of my Activities. Now,
in a any given activity, how do I go about adding content on the
screen (say a button in the middle of the screen) in a addition to my
custom component thats ever present?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a base layout with can contain the header and footer that you use everywhere and then have a stub in the middle that you can inflate with whatever you like?

I think that will solve your problem.

You can read about ViewStub here: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html